# Why can't I implement a boolean check for a folder?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, boolean, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to check specific folder exists. For example, checking folder named "Downloads" exists. I'm writing using C# Windows Forms app and this is code:

```cs
      //key = Folder Name
     {
      var pathtu = Convert.ToBoolean(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(main,key,SearchOption.AllDirectories));
      if (pathtu == true)
       {
         path[0] = @"c:\Users\"+key;
         File.Move(file.SelectedPath, path[0]);
         label2.Visible = true;
       }
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[System.String]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: "checking if the folder exists" - no. nowhere in your code are you doing this, or anything even close. have you tried `Directory.Exists()` instead?

Comment: You are attempting to convert a directory iterator into a Boolean using `Convert.ToBoolean()`.  That will always fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Directory.Exists(pathtodir)
```

It returns a bool.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists